# How to combine 2 code snippets into 1 in FFMPEG?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have 2 ffmpeg codes as follows:
Code 1: Change speed video and audio

```
ffmpeg -i {input} -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/1.1[v];[0:a]atempo=1.1[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -preset ultrafast "{output}"
```

Code 2: Zoom 5 SECONDS of video after EACH 30 SECONDS

```
ffmpeg -i "{input}" -vf "zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(time,35),5),2,1)':d=1:x=iw/4-(iw/zoom/4):y=ih/4-(ih/zoom/4):fps=23.97" -threads 0 -preset ultrafast "{output}"
```

I want to combine 2 code snippets into 1 code with the same functionality as the 2 code above, I would be very grateful if someone could help me!

Answer (score 0):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -i "{input}" -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS/1.1,zoompan=z='if(lte(mod(time,35),5),2,1)':d=1:x=iw/4-(iw/zoom/4):y=ih/4-(ih/zoom/4):fps=23.97;[0:a]atempo=1.1" -preset ultrafast "{output}"
```